# Display API data

Tags: html

I'm very new to web development. I wrote a Sinatra API that returns XML output. How can I display that on front end, using HTML5, or something simple?

This is the output from api call: curl server/getRecordings

```
<recordings>
    <recording>
        <recordingID>
             1375368828193
        </recordingID>
        <processed>false</processed>
     </recording>
</recordings>
```

Comment: It would be great if you can point me to a technology

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a javascript templating engine. You will have to write a bit fo code to parse the xml and then pass the parsed object into a template to be render. There is a [website here that might help you choose which one to use](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/).